# How to easily set unresolved variables in Postman?

Tags: postman

When retrieving a Postman collection, we often have to set/create our variable collection.

They are highlighted in red in postman:

[image: highlights]

> Unresolved Variable
> This variable is not defined in the active collection, environment or globals.

I'm not able to "simply" set a value for this variable in environment variable.

I would be glad to right click on unresolved variable and set it directly, without creating manually.

[image]

Or, a system to collect all collection variable and set them as an empty value.

Any hints to speed-up this?

Answer (score 14):

This is caused by not clicking on "Save" after creating the variable.

Notice that the "Save" button is enabled indicating that there are some unsaved changes. This causes the "Unresolved variable" error:

[image]
[image]

After saving:
[image]
[image]

Comment: A small gotcha is that the variable name is whitespace sensitive - `{{ host }}` won't work, but `{{host}}` will.